# How to make jquery functions run one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, reveal.js

I am using this to run a jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#customer_popup_notes').reveal();</script>

<script type="text/javascript">$('#customer_on_hold').reveal();</script>
```

Rather than both of these running at the same time when the page loads, how can I make them run one at a time?

They are popup boxes that appear when the page loads - so I want to:

1. make the first one load,
2. then when the box is closed, the second one will load.
3. and so on...

Comment: I looked at the source code of `reveal` and it looks like the author didn't integrate it properly with `.animate` - unless I'm missing something. Can you look at how to do chaining with `.animate` and then see if any of those methods work on `reveal`?

Comment: im not too great with jquery - could you explain please?

Comment: My bad - I misread.  Sorry!

Comment: Is this [Foundation's reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) you're using?

Comment: i think it is, i got the code from http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Comment: You should use calllbacks

Comment: @Joren - The plugin in question does not have any callback options.  It will mean editing the plugin and adding them.

Comment: @user2710234 The link that Andy gave is for a different version of what you linked.  It appears to accept callback parameters, so you could pass it a function to execute when the dialog is closed.

Comment: @Archer hmmm okay, how would i do this?

Comment: I think @TanNguyen has got it below.  It creates its own events and triggers them internally.  You may be able to attach your own event handlers to these events, as he's shown.

Answer (score 0):

Since reveal does not have any official documents about this, I quickly read through the source code and give it a try. Hope it will help

```
$('#customer_popup_notes').bind('reveal:close', function(){
  $('#customer_on_hold').reveal();
})

$('#customer_popup_notes').reveal();
```

Updated:
Based on the code https://github.com/zurb/reveal/blob/master/jquery.reveal.js, you have 2 events: `reveal:open`, `reveal:close`

Comment: I have added this in but now it won't close at all

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Foundation at the moment, so this is a best guess based on the documentation.

Store the modal id descriptors in an array, and set the index to 0.

```
var arr = ['#customer_popup_notes', '#customer_on_hold', 'modal3', 'modal4'];
var index = 0;
```

Have a function that loads the modals based on the index and advances the index.

```
function loadModal () {
  $(arr[index]).foundation('reveal', 'open');
  index++;
}
```

Load the initial modal (index = 0).

```
loadModal();
```

When the `close-reveal-modal` class is clicked wait until the modal closes (automatically - this is part of reveal), and then loads the next modal in the array.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-reveal-modal', function () {
  $(arr[index - 1]).foundation('reveal', 'close');
  if (index < arr.length) { setTimeout(loadModal, 300); }
});
```

It assumes your modal looks something like this (note the anchor with `class="close-reveal-modal"`).

```
<div id="customer_popup_notes" class="reveal-modal">
  <h2>Awesome. I have it 1.</h2>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqvsN/6/) that tries to explain the concept using clickable divs.

Comment: in my code... i have copied what you put above and its only displaying the first one

Comment: @user2710234 - try my amended answer. I've just tested this with the latest version of Foundation.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using a callback in the reveal method?

```
$('#customer_popup_notes').reveal(function(){
  $('#customer_on_hold').reveal();
});
```